# Join 2 tables for withdrawals and deposits?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen many people create one unique table for withdrawals and deposits, and a category field to fill with "w" or "d" to specify any record.

Since I needed different fields for W or D I've decided to create 2 different tables, but now I don't know how to join them.

They have a common field "timestamp" (the timestamp of the registration that should be unique)

How can I create a single table in mysql like:

time stamp --- amount widthdrawal --- amount deposits  ???

I know left or right join but I need a Join on both sides I think :S

Comment: you are looking for full outer join. you do it with union, left join, right join

Comment: You might be having a Column which is common to both the tables like 'account number'. Use that and join them ..later group them according to your requirement either on 'W/D' or 'timestamp desc'

Comment: ofc join by unique ID if you have it

Comment: You do want a `JOIN` you want a `UNION`, you'll have to harmonise the schema of the two sets to do that. I can't do that for you unless you detail the schemas more.

Answer (score 1):

simulated full outer join:

```
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.value as withdrawals, t2.value as deposits FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
UNION
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.value as withdrawals, t2.value as deposit FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
```

without join:

```
select timestamp, sum(withdrawal) as withdrawal, sum(deposit) as deposit 
from 
(
select timestamp, withdrawal,0 as deposit from withdrawal
union all
select timestamp, 0 as withdrawal, deposit from deposit
) group by timestamp
```

Comment: what is the "0" in the subquery?

Comment: that is to define the whole column with a constant, 0 in this case.
basically, it inserts the value 0 as integer.
For union, you need the same number of columns, preferably with the same data type. Since from the Withdrawal table we have no deposit info, we can create the column Deposit with value 0. Same for the other table, in reverse. When unioned, you will have the entries coming from Withdrawal, with withdraw values, 0 for deposit, and then the rows from deposit, with deposit values in deposit column, and 0 in withdrawal column.

Comment: @AdrianBR: You should use UNION ALL to avoid an unneccessary DISTINCT step.

Comment: @Gabz union all stacks all rows from the two tables. union stacks only the distinct rows. In the second query, union all does the same as union, but union all is faster since a check for duplicates will not be made. In the first query, union is necessary.

Comment: i edited the previous comment. I wrote it on the wrong answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN why don't you keep the single table for both withdrawals and deposits?

When you need two columns it's just a

```
SELECT
   ts_col,
   MIN(CASE WHEN TransactionIndicator = 'D' THEN amount END) AS Deposits,
   MIN(CASE WHEN TransactionIndicator = 'W' THEN amount END) AS withDrawal
FROM tab
GROUP BY ts_col
```

And if you don't need both withdrawals and deposits on a single row you don't need MIN/GROUP BY.

Btw, deposit and withdrawal for a single transaction will be the same value, isn't it?

Comment: @AdrianBR: That's why i wrote: "why don't you keep the single table?" Two tables result in much more complex queries.

Comment: I know... but I've decided to use two different tables because apart from "timestamp" and "amount" I needed two different structures for the two tables

Comment: Then i would go with AdrianBR's 2nd version (plus UNION ALL).

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions and, asserting that joining on the millisecond is nonsensical, [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4a48/3).

```
CREATE TABLE Withdrawl
(
    Timestamp TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,
    Amount Decimal(60, 4)
);

CREATE TABLE Deposit
(
    Timestamp TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,
    Amount Decimal(60, 4)
);

SELECT
        Timestamp,
        -Amount
    FROM
        Withdrawl
UNION ALL
SELECT
        Timestamp,
        Amount
    FROM
        Deposit
    ORDER BY
        Timestamp ASC;
```

---

how about [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4a48/5),

```
SELECT
        Timestamp,
        Amount,
        NULL
    FROM
        Withdrawl
UNION ALL
SELECT
        Timestamp `time stamp`,
        NULL `amount withdrawal`,
        Amount `amount deposits`
    FROM
        Deposit
    ORDER BY
        Timestamp ASC;
```

Comment: I feel a UNION ALL is what he's going for - unless there is a key linking the two tables together, this is exactly what I'd expect to see.

Comment: It wasn't what I was searching, because it doesn't output the table as I tought, but it might work

Comment: I never understood why people always write "-1 * Amount" instead of a simple "-Amount"?

Comment: @dnoeth, its a throwback to times of yore.

Comment: @Gabz, I've extended to meet your "specification".